# IE: Javascript onchange function getting empty value

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

Why this Simple Javascript function not working in Internet Explorer Version 8.
Why myvalue is empty in Internet Explorer.

```
javascript debug myvalue==
```

This is working fine in Chrome/Firefox and shows the selected value correctly.

```
javascript debug myvalue=Item2=
```

Code

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function showValue(myvalue)
{
   document.write("javascript debug myvalue=" + myvalue + "=\n");
}
</script>

<body>

<select id="items" onchange="showValue(this.value);">
 <option>Item1</option>
 <option>Item2</option>
 <option>Item3</option>
</select>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you don't have VALUES in your options. Something like this will work:

```
<option value="VALUE1">TEXT1</option>
```

But, if you actually need option's TEXT and not VALUE, you should use this:

```
var e = document.getElementById("items");
var txt = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
```

Refer to [HTMLOptionElement DOM spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-70901257) for more info on options.

Comment: Correct - may what he wants if actually the text of the options element.

Answer (score 0):

If you were to use instead of this.value, this.options[this.selectedIndex], it might work in IE8 (which I don't have).